# Is white vinegar the same as White Wine vinegar?

Tags: substitutions, vinegar

Is white vinegar, aka the stuff just labelled as "vinegar" in the US and which I use for cleaning my kettle, the same as "White wine vinegar", which I have purchased on accident a time or two? If not, what is white vinegar made of?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, it's not. White vinegar (also known as distilled vinegar) is made of acetic acid diluted in distilled water. Its flavor is simple—its just sour. Typical concentrations range from 5–7% acetic acid.

White wine vinegar is made by allowing white wine to turn to vinegar. It has a much more complex flavor profile. It is also frequently less sour (acidic) than distilled white vinegar.

Comment: (I appreciate this is a USA question - but just for trivia sake; in the UK this legally cannot be called vinegar and must be labelled "non-brewed condiment". White [Distilled] Vinegar in the UK is generally made from distilling malt [barley] vinegar)

Answer (score 2):

White wine vinegar is a completely different thing, it's less tangy and is more diluted as it's made from the white wine. The Ethanol in the white wine is let to oxidise into ethanoic acid, which is a carbolyxic acid also known as vinegar.

Comment: the acetic/ethanoic acid is normally produced by fermentation rather than oxidization.

Answer (score -3):

They are different. You can drink white wine before it turns to vinegar but if you drink distilled water and acetic acid you’re nuts.